# Does the retail version (3189) of Supreme Commander support bloom rendering?

Tags: supreme-commander

In the process of working around a problem in my Linux + [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/) + [Supreme Commander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supreme_Commander_%28video_game%29) + SC patch 3280 setup, I had to disable [bloom rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_%28shader_effect%29) in the graphics options. The retail version (3189), however, does not seem to have the same problem, even at the maximum graphics quality settings.

Does the retail version (3189) of Supreme Commander support bloom rendering? Because if bloom rendering was added in one of the later patches, it might explain the regression.

Answer (score 2):

it does however, on linux you have to turn off antialiasing for it to work.

the game looks fine without anti aliasing. I think low values for anti aliasing also work.

took me awhile to figure this one out :)

Comment: Wow! An answer after 6 years! FWIW, these days I have been (rather sporadically) playing [FAF](https://www.faforever.com) on Linux and it is generally working fine. I guess WINE has advanced a fair bit in the past few years...

Comment: yeah sorry I didn't know about this community before. everything happens on the faf forums. we have a real active linux thread there. I produced an auto-install & setup script for linux and that's were I recently found out about how to turn bloom on. I still had this issue.